# Settings menu of main menu not updating in settings menu of pause menu. Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a main menu scene and a gameplay scene with a pause menu in my game, both of them have a Settings Menu but **if i change the values of, for example, the dropdown for Graphics Quality from the main menu scene, the changes wont update in pause menu in the game scene, but it will still be applied for the project**. I've been searching solutions but found nothing exactly about this topic... Is there a way to do that, or do i have to put the main menu in the same scene as the gameplay scene?

Comment: why am i getting downvoted

Comment: Because of lack of information? People don't know how you designed the system, thus no way to find out what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I do not have enough reputation to comment.

Anyway, you have to load the settings every time the settings menu is enabled, the UI will have their default value. If you're saving the values in a file or playerpref, you have to load that and set the sliders and stuff in your UI accordingly.